# Solving a block and share relationship [pool mining]

Tags: mining-pools, difficulty, mining-pool-shares

I have a somewhat odd question. I am currently pool mining and it is telling me my best share and the difficulty (this is an altcoin but same question applies). My miner is telling me my best share was 16.7K and the difficulty is a little over 100, does it matter what my 'best share' is for that round? How do I know when I solve a block in the pool? I hope this made sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your share is better than the difficulty you have solved a block. Other than that, the best share is only for your information/amusement. Although, some pools only count shares above a certain difficulty towards the work one has provided.

Even succeeding at the difficulty, you could still not be discovering a block for one of the following reasons:

1. The difficulty you were looking at was the difficulty at which the pool is accepting shares as work, instead of the networks difficulty.
2. You were working on a stale block chain.
3. Another block was found at the same time and was accepted right before yours.

Comment: Would there be any reason for my shares (that are higher than the difficulty) that they do not count towards solving a block?

Comment: Either you were working on a stale block chain, or another block was found at the same time and was accepted right before yours. Does the coin have a very high block frequency?

Comment: Targeted for 2.5 minutes, I can see why most aren't solving blocks. Thank you